# How does 3rd party analytics libraries track screen views just by importing their library

Tags: ios

For example in Firebase Analytics they have automatic screen tracking: "Analytics automatically tracks some information about screens in your application, such as the class name of the UIViewController or Activity that is currently in focus." https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews

How do they achieve this? I do not use Firebase Analytics and I was wondering how I can use the same technology for my own app.

Comment: My best guess is Accessibility notifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityscreenchangednotification

Comment: From what I've seen, these libraries usually swizzle the various view controller lifecycle methods (`viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, etc.) to keep track of which view controllers have been shown or are currently in focus. And the swizzling is done in an Objective-C category's `+load` method (inside the library) that is automatically invoked when the `-ObjC` linker flag is set.